# How to reduce the size of image before uploading it to firebase storage?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage, android-glide

I have made an social app for image and video sharing.However,its taking too much time for loading the image.I am using the glide library.Please, tell me how can I reduce the size of image picked up from gallery without considerable change in quality of image (like Instagram do) and then upload it to firebase storage.Please help!

Comment: post your code here

Comment: This sounds like a problem that must have been solved before. Did you try anything? These look promising: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D+How+to+reduce+the+size+of+image

Comment: Instagram (and many other social media apps) transcode images at lower resolutions and/or in different formats (like webp) so they can serve an appropriate quality image as fast as possible. IG also gets a crazy low quality photo immediately and blurs it with the loading screen, which is a nice effect. You can use tools like imgix or cloudinary to get on-the-fly resized, compressed, photos, or build your own using the GAE Images API (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/)

Comment: How can I do this when uploading from JavaScript?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
StorageReference childRef2 = [your firebase storage path]
storageRef.child(UserDetails.username+"profilepic.jpg");
                    Bitmap bmp = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 25, baos);
                    byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
                    //uploading the image
                    UploadTask uploadTask2 = childRef2.putBytes(data);
                    uploadTask2.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            Toast.makeText(Profilepic.this, "Upload successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(Profilepic.this, "Upload Failed -> " + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });`
```

just go ahead and do above steps it will reduce your image size and upload it on firebase it reduce the image size upto 1 to 2 mb 
like on my experience 4mb file became 304kb .

`filepath` is and `File` object of your selected image. :)

Comment: thank you so much,,, Perfectly working for me also.. why no upvote for this answer......+10

Comment: It worked like a charm, thank you! However, the picture is tilted. How can I fix that?

Comment: thanks, it worked perfectly. Reducing the image of size 5.98 MB to 990 KB

Comment: Uploading to firebase rotates the image by this

Comment: Thank you !!! I have been looking around but others didn't seem to work until I tried yours

Answer (score 4):

Here i am using this code to upload compressed image on `firebase storeage`

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode==RC_PHOTO_PICKER && resultCode==RESULT_OK)
        {
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

            Bitmap bmp = null;
            try {
                bmp = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), selectedImageUri);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            //here you can choose quality factor in third parameter(ex. i choosen 25) 
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 25, baos);
            byte[] fileInBytes = baos.toByteArray();

           StorageReference photoref = chatPhotosStorageReference.child(selectedImageUri.getLastPathSegment());

           //here i am uploading
           photoref.putBytes(fileInBytes).addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                       public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                          // When the image has successfully uploaded, we get its download URL
                           mProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);

                           Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                           String id = chatRoomDataBaseReference.push().getKey();
                           String time = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

                           // Set the download URL to the message box, so that the user can send it to the database
                           FriendlyMessageModel friendlyMessage = new FriendlyMessageModel(id,null, userId, downloadUrl.toString(),time);
                   chatRoomDataBaseReference.child(id).setValue(friendlyMessage);
                                       }
                   });
        }
    }
```

Comment: it worked, compressed the image from 1.32 mb to 323 kbs

Answer (score 0):

I have done the same for uploading image to firebase using bitmap.compress

```
private void postDataToFirebase() {
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Posting the Blog to Firebase");
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);

        final String titleValue = mPostTitle.getText().toString();
        final String description = mPostDescription.getText().toString();
        if((!TextUtils.isEmpty(titleValue))&& (!TextUtils.isEmpty(description)) && bitmap != null)
        {
            mProgressDialog.show();
            StorageReference filePath = mStorage.child("Blog_Images").child(imagePathName);
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 20, bytes);
            String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(PostActivity.this.getContentResolver(), bitmap, imagePathName, null);
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);
            filePath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                    Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

                    DatabaseReference newPost = mDatabaseReference.push();
                    newPost.child("Title").setValue(titleValue);
                    newPost.child("Desc").setValue(description);
                    newPost.child("imageUrl").setValue(downloadUrl.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "Data Posted Successfully to Firebase server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(PostActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

        }

    }
```

**bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat format, int quality, OutputStream stream)**

you can change the quality of the bitmap and compress it.

Comment: what is your imagePathName?

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin version

```
    val userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid
    val storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("UsersPhotos/${userId}.jpg")

    // compressing image
    val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver, imageURI)
    val byteArrayOutputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 25, byteArrayOutputStream)
    val reducedImage: ByteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()

        storageRef.putBytes(reducedImage)
        .addOnSuccessListener {

            Log.i("xxx", "Success uploading Image to Firebase!!!")

            storageRef.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener {

                //getting image url
                Log.i("xxx",it.toString())
            
             }.addOnFailureListener {

                        Log.i("xxx", "Error getting image download url")
                    }

        }.addOnFailureListener {

            Log.i("xxx", "Failed uploading image to server")
            
        }
```