# Way to reduce size of array of images before uploading to firebase storage?

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-storage

Is there a way in which we can reduce the size of multiple images before uploading them to the firebase storage. Basically, reducing the size of images stored in an array before uploading them.

Comment: Have you checked this? [How to reduce the size of image before uploading it to firebase storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41611294/how-to-reduce-the-size-of-image-before-uploading-it-to-firebase-storage)

Comment: Yes, but it for a single image. I have a string array of images that takes the path of the images. So its like on button click, all of them are uploaded one by one.

Comment: Have you tried Dharmaraj's solution for each image in the array?

Comment: Yes I did, but baos didn't work for me..it gave an error.